# Link to configurable product that avoids price change

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, price, google-shopping

Magento offers the ability to link to a configurable product with options already specified by adding the attribute id and option to the query string, like this:

```
www.example.com/product-link.html?166=475
```

However, when this option increases or decreases the price, the initial price is shown first and then the increase/decrease is shown a moment later after a JavaScript script changes it. This causes problems for our Google shopping feed, as Google's automated price checking records the base configurable product price while the correct, adjusted price for the associated product is reported in our feed.

Is there a simple way to link to an associated product and have the price appear immediately, or will I need to adjust the code to make this work?

We want the product link in our Google shopping ads to link to the configurable product page, so linking to a simple product page does not solve the problem.

Comment: I have no solutions available but I was wondering if you were ever able to figure out a solution to this problem? I'm currently dealing with the exact same issue. Tried bypassing the issue with URL parameters, but no luck. Tried serving products to Google using an item_group_id and variants, but no luck. Tried updating microdata to be much more clear and concise, but no luck. If you have anything id be very appreciative.

Comment: Please add new question and include link of this post. You will get better response then. Thanks

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/138066)